How can I use sed to replace specific characters within a substring between delimiters?
I need to process a large json file, in which I need to change hyphens to underscore in values of a specific key, for example within the file I would change:
{
  "key": ["test-value-1", "value-2"],
  "anotherKey": "unrelated-value"
}

to:
{
  "key": ["test_value_1", "value_2"],
  "anotherKey": "unrelated-value"
}

without modifying the values of other keys. I think the problem can be generalised to replacing all the occurrences of a specific character between delimiters, in my case:

the character to be replaced is -,
the replacement is _,
the delimiters are "key": [ and ].

How can I achieve that using sed?
Note: I am using a macos, not sure if that matters.
So far I have managed to replace the entire value list with:
sed -E 's/"key": \[(.*)\]/"key": \["replaced_value"\]/'

for example:
$ echo '{"key": ["test-value-1", "value-2"], "anotherKey": "unrelated-value"}' | sed -E 's/"key": \[(.*)\]/"key": \["replaced_value"\]/'
{"key": ["replaced_value"], "anotherKey": "unrelated-value"}

I am not sure how to further operate on the value captured with the regular expression to replace only specific character within it.

SO is a professional Q/A website. Parsing JSON with sed is a bad idea, better use your favorite language to process the JSON properly with a JSON parser. Python, Perl, Ruby...

I would start working with ChatGPT. It immediately gave me a working answer to your question with jq.

echo '...' |  sed '/"key"/{s/-/_/g}' works, but probably not for you real world data AND will lead you down a rabbit-hole of reg-ex hell (-; (note the single quotes on the echo). Learn to use the jq . Good luck.

You can just let sed replace all - with _ where the line contains "key"::
sed '/"key":/ s/-/_/g' /tmp/json


But using jq this is much more safer / easier with gsub:
jq '.key[] |= gsub("-"; "_")' /tmp/json

Online Demo

Both produce:
{
  "key": ["test_value_1", "value_2"],
  "anotherKey": "unrelated-value"
}


Good jq shot, good to know for gsub trick

Thanks, I was not familiar with jq, it seems like a much better approach then sed for my use case. Could you please elaborate further about how can I execute this replacement on a json file that can have the "key" nested in any location in the json object? I.e. nested and repeated on different levels

That's probably different for how your json looks like. Can you add an example in. your question?

I was hoping to cover different structures with a single solution, without the need to know how the json will look like in advance. I am gonna read up on jq, maybe there is a way to deeply iterate over the entire object and perform this operation on any matching key. Thanks for your help!

Yea there a quite some questions like that, something like this would probably do the job, or maybe even in combination of ..
